# Invalid Scopes: read_stream error in facebook

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api, tornado, facebook-oauth

I am trying to run [this tornado facebook application](https://github.com/tornadoweb/tornado/tree/master/demos/facebook) but I am continuously getting this error after passing my login credentials on facebook.

[image]

In my client Oauth settings, I have enabled both client and web login. Could anyone help me to get rid of this error?

My oauth settings [Oauth settings](https://www.pinterest.com/pin/429953095654969164/)

My app settings [app settings](https://www.pinterest.com/pin/429953095654969159/)

UPDATE: I followed the suggestions by @CBroe and able to get rid of `read_stream error` but now if I navigate to the `url http://localhost:8888/` I am getting `facebook auth error`. Response :

```
HTTPResponse(
    _body=None,
    buffer=<_io.BytesIO object at 0x7ffa8afdcb30>,
    code=400,
    effective_url='https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8888%2Fauth%2Flogin%3Fnext%3D%252F',
    error=HTTPError('HTTP 400: Bad Request',),
    headers={
        'Content-Length': '124',
        'X-Fb-Trace-Id': 'GxhzOGi+bkT',
        'Expires': 'Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT',
        'X-Fb-Stats-Contexts': ': api,: V3',
        'X-Fb-Debug': 'w/17ADPQTa1QPtfbFYGIyV8csiXU5ai2i2VqukGJ2QmzPln6blmLFRiv0SVRSLBFFyAawOvHjfrFnjbtam/HRQ==',
        'X-Fb-Rev': '2007633',
        'Connection': 'close',
        'Pragma': 'no-cache',
        'Cache-Control': 'no-store',
        'Date': 'Sat, 24 Oct 2015 10:11:49 GMT',
        'Facebook-Api-Version': 'v2.0',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        'Content-Type': 'text/javascript; charset=UTF-8',
        'Www-Authenticate': 'OAuth "Facebook Platform" "invalid_code" "This authorization code has been used."'
    },
    reason='Bad Request',
    request=<tornado.httpclient.HTTPRequest object at 0x7ffa8b00f290>,
    request_time=0.12035489082336426,
    time_info={}
)
```

In my client Oauth settings, I have enabled both client and web login. My `website url` and `Oauth redirect url` also matches but still I am getting this error. Could anyone help me here? Any pointer will be helpful.

Comment: `read_stream` permission does not exist any more. The error message has pointed you to the documentation section that lists the currently available permissions already – so _read_ it.

Comment: How will I disable the read stream permission then ?

Comment: You figure out where in the code the scope is specified, and remove it …

Comment: My friend ran the same code and it worked for him. Code is here [link](https://github.com/tornadoweb/tornado/tree/master/demos/facebook)

Comment: This is the code we ran [link](https://github.com/tornadoweb/tornado/blob/master/demos/facebook/facebook.py). How it worked for him, but not for me? Any pointers

Comment: It might have worked at the time that code was originally written, when there still was a `read_stream` permission. And it also asks for `offline_access`, which was removed _ages_ ago …

Comment: We both ran at the same time today, not long ago. It worked on his laptop, but not for me :( :(

Comment: Our App settings are exactly same, I spent like an hour to match  it but it is not working for me.

Comment: As the error message says, it is only shown to developers of the FB app in question – for normal users, it does not show that message, but simply ignores any invalid permissions silently. And there is no way that the other app actually asked the user for that permission – because it _does not exists any more_. So see to it that you remove it from the code.

Comment: Okay let me explain this: He created an app on Facebook then ran the same program on his laptop, it worked. I created an app on facebook the ran the exactly same program, but it showed me this `read_stream error`. We both are running the app on localhost, and we are developers.

Comment: My oauth settings [Oauth settings](https://www.pinterest.com/pin/429953095654969164/)

My app settings [app settings](https://www.pinterest.com/pin/429953095654969159/) his settings are exactly same.

Comment: Read what it says about `read_stream` permission here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_4_deprecations – that is all there is to say about it, any further discussion will not change the facts.

Comment: How should I get rid of this error then? and any idea what can be a possibility that my friend is not getting this error?

Comment: I already told you twice, that you need to remove it from the code.

Comment: Yes, I removed the read_stream line from the code but now it says `Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings.` My app URL is `http://localhost:8888/`.

Comment: You need to fill in the Valid OAuth Redirect URIs field.

Comment: I am running the app on localhost and `site url is http://localhost:8888/`. This should be valid, you can also check my screenshots on my question.

Comment: Also checkout the screenshot [link](https://www.pinterest.com/pin/429953095654969159/) my Oauth Redirect field is valid.

Comment: That’s the wrong one. And in the other one, the field is _empty_.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on this? Why this is wrong, and what do you mean by other field? I am so sorry for asking so many questions :/ but I will be really grateful if you could help me with this error.

Comment: You see that there is a field with the label “Valid OAuth Redirect URIs”, yes? You need to input the value of the `redirect_uri` parameter that gets used in your login dialog call in there. (And if you’re not sure what it is, then check the browser address bar when the dialog is shown. The value in there is likely going to be URL-encoded, so that needs to be undone before you input the value into that field.)

Comment: I don't have any `“Valid OAuth Redirect URIs”` field as you can see in the screenshot as well. I have `app domain` and `site url`, and both contains `http://localhost:8888/` as redirect url

Comment: You did show _two_ screenshots, and if you don’t see what I am talking about in one of them, then you can not even be bothered to go check the other one again, to see if maybe that one might be the one containing the field I am talking about?

Comment: Now I am getting `HTTPError(500, "Facebook auth failed")` :( :( passing the correct login credentials

Comment: Seems like even the login page is not opening now after I `Valid OAuth redirect URIs - http://localhost:8888/`. On the my command line it is showing `facebook auth error`

Comment: I have updated my question, and now I am getting `facebook auth error`